# How i rearrange a List in python based on another List

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to re arrange a List (or create a new List) based on some condition:

I have a List :

`fixedList = ['116','117','114','99','102','101','95']`

`unorderedList = ['99','116','117']`

i want to make new List like:

`newList = ['116','117','99']`.

the item of **newList** is based on **unorderedList**, and the ordering is based on **fixedList**

Comment: What is the expected behavior if `newList` has duplicates?

Comment: i assure newList (from unorderedList) cannot have duplicates. although basiccaly List can have duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom sort where the key to sort on is the index in the fixed list, for example:

```
fixedList = ['116','117','114','99','102','101','95']
unorderedList = ['99','116','117']
newList = sorted(unorderedList, key=fixedList.index)
```

The output is:

```
['116', '117', '99']
```

Comment: `lambda x:fixedList.index(x)` can be `fixedList.index`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[el for el in fixedList if el in unorderedList]
```

The output is as expected

```
['116', '117', '99']
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
sorted(unorderedList, key=fixedList.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.isin

```
import numpy as np

fixedList = ['116','117','114','99','102','101','95']
unorderedList = ['99','116','117']

# isin returns a boolean array of the same shape as element 
# that is True where an element of unorderedList is in fixedList and False otherwise.

mask = np.isin(np.array(fixedList), np.array(unorderedList))

#Now form new list using mask
newlist = (np.array(fixedList)[mask]).tolist()
```

## Now new list contains the below content

## ['116', '117', '99']

Refer https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Comment: unfortunately the IDE doesnt support numpy. but thankyou for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2): 
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2] 
    return lst3

fixedList = ['116','117','114','99','102','101','95']
unorderedList = ['99','116','117']

print( intersection(fixedList,unorderedList))
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-two-lists/